# Changing of button text in javascript onclick

Tags: javascript

i want to change of button text when i click the button. Here i have added the text **Click me again** but its not showing.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").classList.add("customBtn");

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".bodyBG").classList.toggle("bodyBG1");
  document.querySelector(".btn").value="click me again!";
})
```

```css
body{
  background: lightpink;
}

.customBtn{
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding : 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
}

.bodyBG1{
  background: green !important;
}
```

```html
<body class="bodyBG">
  <button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: `.value` is usually used for `input` elements, you can use `.textContent` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. By the way, no need to select the same element several times, just assign it to a variable.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  button.innerText = 'click me again!';
});
```

```html
<body class="bodyBG">
  <button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
</body>
```